# When is it safe to delete the Tomcat 8 /temp directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tomcat, tomcat8

I have the following Python pseudocode to remove the contents of the `/temp` directory in Tomcat 8.

`start` is called when the server is started.  My integration tests are failing, and the server is failing to start at all.  I'm not a Tomcat expert, so I'm wondering when it's safe to delete any directories on the server.  I'm trying to delete the temporary files and logs (I believe under `/temp` and `/log`).

When there is an error on deleting the directories, I still want the server to start.

```
def start(server_name):
    if (is_running):
         clean = False
    else:
         clean = _clean_directories(server_name)
         // start the server


def _clean_directories(server_name):
    directory = // create absolute path to directory with `server_name`
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to empty logs and work when Tomcat is not running although there are risks to doing so.

Deleting logs means you lose the ability to use the logs to investigate old issues.

Deleting work means any JSPs there were compiled on-the-fly will need to be re-compiled on next access.

From Tomcat's perspective, it is also safe to delete temp when Tomcat is not running. Whether it is safe from an application perspective depends on the application and how it uses temp - if at all.